# Predict probability from Cox PH model

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am trying to use cox model to predict the probability of failure after time (which is named stop) 3.

```
bladder1 <- bladder[bladder$enum < 5, ] 
coxmodel = coxph(Surv(stop, event) ~ (rx + size + number)  + 
        cluster(id), bladder1)
range(predict(coxmodel, bladder1, type = "lp"))
range(predict(coxmodel, bladder1, type = "risk"))
range(predict(coxmodel, bladder1, type = "terms"))
range(predict(coxmodel, bladder1, type = "expected"))
```

However, the outputs of predict function are all not in 0-1 range. Is there any function or how can I use the lp prediction and baseline hazard function to calculate probability?

Comment: summary(survfit(coxmodel,newdata)) provides probabilites on the time periods of orignal model/data instead of new data ..so survfit is more skeptical to handle with newdata

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please read the help page for `predict.coxph`. None of those are supposed to be probabilities. The linear predictor for a specific set of covariates is the log-hazard-ratio relative to a hypothetical (and very possibly non-existent) case with the mean of all the predictor values. The 'expected' comes the closest to a probability since it is a predicted number of events, but it would require specification of the time and then be divided by the number at risk at the beginning of observation.

In the case of the example offered on that help page for `predict`, you can see that the sum of predicted events is close the the actual number:

```
> sum(predict(fit,type="expected"), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 163

> sum(lung$status==2)
[1] 165
```

I suspect you may want to be working instead with the `survfit` function, since the probability of event is 1-probability of survival.

```
?survfit.coxph
```

The code for a similar question appears here: [Adding column of predicted Hazard Ratio to dataframe after Cox Regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516275/adding-column-of-predicted-hazard-ratio-to-dataframe-after-cox-regression-in-r/30518147#30518147)

Since you suggested using the bladder1 dataset, then this would be the code for a specification of time=5

```
 summary(survfit(coxmodel), time=5)
#------------------
Call: survfit(formula = coxmodel)

 time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
    5    302      26    0.928  0.0141        0.901        0.956
```

That would return as a list with the survival prediction as a list element named `$surv`:

```
> str(summary(survfit(coxmodel), time=5))
List of 14
 $ n       : int 340
 $ time    : num 5
 $ n.risk  : num 302
 $ n.event : num 26
 $ conf.int: num 0.95
 $ type    : chr "right"
 $ table   : Named num [1:7] 340 340 340 112 NA 51 NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "records" "n.max" "n.start" "events" ...
 $ n.censor: num 19
 $ surv    : num 0.928
 $ std.err : num 0.0141
 $ lower   : num 0.901
 $ upper   : num 0.956
 $ cumhaz  : num 0.0744
 $ call    : language survfit(formula = coxmodel)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "summary.survfit"
> summary(survfit(coxmodel), time=5)$surv
[1] 0.9282944
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there anyway to specify the follow-up time for type expected?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! This gave me the right direction to final solution.

Comment: In case of type = 'expected', can we divide each prediction to the sum (which is 163) and treat them as probabilities?

Comment: I think you would need to post an example of such a calculation with a particular dataset in order to find what you are intending. You might want to sum the probabilities you derive to see how well they match the full dataset.