# Plotting survival curves with time dependent covariates in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I've been trying for multiple days to visualize my Cox regression with time-dependent covariates with no luck. I'd like to isolate one  of two time-dependent covariates to visualize its effect on survival probability, risk, hazard ratio, and/or expected failures while holding the other variable constant at its mean.

As an example, I'm using data from the `pbc` dataset from the `survival` package in R. The data is set up as follows using the `tmerge` function:

```
data("pbc", package = "survival")
head(pbc)[, c(1:5, 11, 12)]
head(pbcseq)[, c(1, 4:5, 7, 12, 13)]

pbc <- pbc %>% mutate(bili = log(bili), protime = log(protime)) # log = e^x = y; y = bili
pbcseq <- pbcseq %>% mutate(bili = log(bili), protime = log(protime))

temp <- subset(pbc, id <= 312, select = c(id:sex)) # baseline
pbc2 <- tmerge(temp, temp, id = id, death = event(time, status)) #set range
pbc2 <- tmerge(pbc2, pbcseq, id = id, bili = tdc(day, bili),
  protime = tdc(day, protime))

fit <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, death == 2) ~ bili + protime, pbc2)
```

What I'd like to do is make a new dataframe to predict over using the output from the model (`fit`). I'd like to hold the `protime` variable constant at its mean while predicting the effect of `bili` on survival probability, the hazard rate, and/or the number of failures expected. I'd then like to plot these effects.

I've tried using a `survfit` object to plot survival. I've tried using the `expand.grid` function to create a new dataset, but because the new data is not formatted using time intervals I get an error. I've tried the  `make_newdata` function (from `pammtools`) to create a new dataset and then the `predict()` function to apply the model over the new dataset, but it will not take a `survfit` object and I'm not sure how to get my values of interest (survival, hazard, etc) by just using the `fit` model.

I would be SO grateful if someone can help me!!

Comment: This question addresses using `predict()` with `coxph` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993197/predict-probability-from-cox-ph-model What exactly does your code look like that doesn't work?

Comment: Ah! Thank you for linking to those questions. I figured it out. I don't think ```survfit``` works with time-dependent covariates so I stuck with ```coxph``` and was able to calculate survival simply: ```exp(-expected)``` using the ```type = expected``` argument in the ```coxph``` function. Thank you @MrFlick!